# Intercepting CRUD operations on database using EF6 and filtering logs

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, entity-framework-6, interceptor

I am trying to implement logging in my Windows forms app, and I have this code which lets me intercept CRUD operations while using Entity Framework 6:

```
 class EFCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public void NonQueryExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("NonQueryExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void NonQueryExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("NonQueryExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ReaderExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ReaderExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ReaderExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ReaderExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ScalarExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ScalarExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ScalarExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ScalarExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        private void LogInfo(string command, string commandText)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Intercepted on: {0} :- {1} ", command, commandText);
        }
    }
```

Then I add the interceptor like this:

```
public class FE6CodeConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public FE6CodeConfig()
    {
        this.AddInterceptor(new EFCommandInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Now this is all good and works, I mean it is nice little feature...But, I want to log into my database only when a user has inserted, or deleted a record.

So I  need **command name** (Insert or Delete), **table name**, **row id**, and one more field from that table...

Now what I see is that I have DBCommand in these methods. There is a property called Command Text...And which gives output like this:

```
Intercepted on: ReaderExecuting :- IsAsync: False, Command Text: INSERT [dbo].[Student]([FirstName], [StandardId], [LastName])
VALUES (@0, NULL, NULL)
SELECT [StudentID], [RowVersion] FROM [dbo].[Student]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [StudentID] = scope_identity()
Intercepted on: ReaderExecuted :- IsAsync: False, Command Text: INSERT [dbo].[Student]([FirstName], [StandardId], [LastName])
VALUES (@0, NULL, NULL)
SELECT [StudentID], [RowVersion] FROM [dbo].[Student]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [StudentID] = scope_identity()
```

I mean could likely parse all that from the above string...But is there some more convenient way to have this data?

Comment: If you working with Raw query execution, there is no way other than to parse it. But, if you working with EF entities, like .Add(), .Remove() etc - you can just scan Entities for their state in DbContext before SaveChanges executes.

Comment: If the command text is not important for you, as an option you can log in methods of business logic layer.

Comment: @eocron Yes I am working with entities... So you mean to skip using interceptor at all..Hmm :) I could try that... I mean, command text would be fine with me if it has real values, rather than placeholders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with power of EF (not tested the code, but I hope you get the idea):

```
public void MyContext : DbContext
{
   public override int SaveChanges() //not relevant if it is new, you can do it in another method.
   {
       foreach(var e in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
       {
           if(e.State == EntityState.Added)
           {
              //log here
           }
       }
       return base.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

With raw queries you need parser.

Comment: Oh thanks. This works...Just to figure out how to get table name, and values of its fields...Do you know how to do that maybe? By the way, I had to change slightly your code. I needed this in order to work : `var e in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()`

Comment: Thank you, added to answer your fix. Yes it is possible, just iterate them in entity. For *actual* (in SQL database) names of fields and tables it is a bit hard, because needs hacking into EF model. Not worth it for logging.

Comment: `SaveChanges` is virtual, do you need to shadow it?

Comment: In general you should be careful following this approach, as it will log some insert,update, delete, even if `SaveChanges` fail.

Comment: Yeah, this can fail, but logging is non-transactional in general, so...just deal with it =)

Comment: It's more correct if you log after the operation completed successfully. It's not about logging is transaction or not. Anyway, just sharing my two cents ;)

Comment: Yeah, personally, I always pass special context for transaction and accumulate after-transaction actions there: indexing in elastic, cleanup, logging, server cache renewal, etc. This way I minimise non-transactional misbehavious upon error.

Answer (score 1):

As an option instead of intercepting the command execution, you can log in business logic layer:

```
public class ProductBusiness
{
    ILogger logger;

    //...
    public void Create(Product p)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new MyDbContext())
            {
                db.Products.Add(p);
                db.SaveChanges();
                logger.Log($"Create Product - {DateTime.Now} - Id:{p.Id}, Name:{p.Name}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Log($"Error - {DateTime.Now} - {ex.ToString()}");
            throw;
        }
    }
    //...
}
```